# Entity framework in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, orm, entity-framework-4

I was reading a blog post the other day about code-first fluent mappings feature in entity framework ctp4. Just wonder what version of EF comes with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: You have the proper version listed in your tags, so why would you ask again??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework 4.0 has been shipped with .Net Framework 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 and it does NOT contains the *Code First development* and *Fluent API*, to get those, you can download and install EF CTP4 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e&displaylang=en).